# Simplemodal box does not load each time for dynamic html

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal to display a form which is fetched dynamically using ajax.
The first time, it loads w/o any issue. But after that, the form does not open
and I get the following error: 
  $(data).modal is not a function

I have tried loading the script dynamically but that does not really take care
of the problem. Any ideas ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Does the form contain a script tag loading jQuery again? If jQuery is loaded again, the $ object will be overwritten and you will lose the modal plugin.

Comment: The form does not contain any links. The page from where I call the form is also formed dynamically. Don't quite understand why this is happening esp. since this setup was working quite well at one point.

Comment: Without seing any code, it's hard to give you a good answer. Can you reproduce it in JS Fiddle?

Comment: I will describe the structure of my code over here.

 main.html : Includes the simple modal script. Has a button when clicked generates html which is inserted into the page. The generated html has an image which when clicked creates the form from an ajax request. On clicking the image, I am getting the error: $.modal is not a function